# OnBackPressedCallback doesn't work the first time when you put your app in background and comeback

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, onbackpressed

I have a screen that whenever it composes for the first, it adds a `onBackPressedCallback` like this code:

```
    val activity = LocalContext.current.getActivity()

    val dispatcher = LocalOnBackPressedDispatcherOwner.current?.onBackPressedDispatcher

    val backCallback = remember {
        object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
            override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
                activity?.finish()
            }
        }
    }

    DisposableEffect(dispatcher) { // dispose/relaunch if dispatcher changes
        dispatcher?.addCallback(backCallback)
        onDispose {
            backCallback.remove() // avoid leaks!
        }
    }
```

It works like it should, unless you put the app in background and comeback. Then the first time you press back it won't work and the entire screen will be recomposed, while recomposing this time will add the callback and the second time you press the callback it will work.

**Why when you put the app in the background and comeback it doesn't work the first time you press the back button?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should **always** use the prebuilt [`BackHandler` API](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/activity/compose/package-summary#backhandler), part of `activity-compose`. This API automatically handles this (and many other edge cases) for you by ensuring that the internal callback used uses the appropriate `Lifecycle`, thus ensuring that it is re-added in the right ordering after you put your app in the background and come back.

```
val activity = LocalContext.current.getActivity()
BackHandler {
    activity?.finish()
}
```

Comment: Yes, looks like I saw an old post from 2020 and understood that I should copy and paste. it  Thank you!

Comment: I donno why but BackHandler does not resolve for me.

Comment: @Mahdi you need to add a dependency for `androidx.activity:activity-compose` and probably `androidx.activity:activity` if you don't already have it.